# Copy all files from one directory to another or copy entire directory

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on Linux machine and I'm trying to copy the entire folder from a SRC to DST using c++11 (no filesystem as in C++17)

For now, the solution I implemented creates a new DEST directory and then copy all the filw with system();

So this is code that actually creates a folder and then execute a cp command
to copy all files

```
void backupConfigurationFolder()
{
    string folderName;

    string tempName = "_cfg/";
    folderName = _config.logFileBasePath + tempName;

    check = mkdir(folderName.c_str(), 0777);

    if (!check)
        printf("Directory created\n");
    else {
        printf("Unable to create directory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    string command = "cp cfg/*.* " + folderName;
    system(command.c_str());
}
```

I wish to find a different way instead of using system()
thanks

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the problem you're trying to fix.

Comment: You can ask "how to copy all files ...?", but if you ask "How to make my solution more robust... ?" you need to show us your solution.

Comment: `boost` has [filesystem](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).